# What's the deal with questions starting with "What's the deal with"?

Tags: discussion, title-wording

I'm seeing those more and more often recently. "What's the deal with" is a slang, I don't think we should allow it.

Instead, we should be using "Who is/are?" or "What is/are?". I think these are more appropriate. Examples:

- <s>What's the deal with</s> Who is Ichigo's Father, Isshin?
- <s>What's the deal with</s> What is the barrier at the end of Digimon Tamers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not really slang but the problem with it is that it makes all questions look the same... We should encourage choosing other wordings.

The best way to do that is editing the questions when they come up. :) Forcing is not feasible and it's better to educate. It'll be slower but will give more results in the long term.

Comment: Indeed, I'm merely asking about the community's concensus on this one. Also, it does sound a bit like slang, like stand-up comedy shows "What's up with that?!"

Comment: @MadaraUchiha There are examples of the same wording in other sites too, by the way.

Comment: That doesn't make it right, you know.

Comment: "Right"... It's not wrong, there are other preferred ways yes, but it's not wrong. I agree with you that we should encourage more diverse ways of asking, though.

Comment: "What is" is not a synonym of it, though. "What's the deal with" is the same as asking "What are the properties of" or "What is the situation regarding". As an example, you would *not* ask 'What are the questions starting with “What's the deal with”?'